# Spivak, Ch 2 Prologue, Problem 13: how to prove $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational using fact that $k^2$ divisible by 3 means k is also divisible by 3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem 13 in Spivak's chapter 2 Prologue is to prove $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{5}$, and $\sqrt{6}$ are irrational with the hint that to treat $\sqrt{3}$ you can use the fact that every integer can be written in the form $3n$, $3n+1$, or $3n+2$.

Let's just consider the $\sqrt{3}$ case, because the other two are analogous. The question here is simply about one step in the proof, namely the part with divisibility by three explained below.

The solution at the back of Spivak for $\sqrt{3}$ is as follows:

$(3n+1)^2 = 9n^2+6n+1 = 3(3n^2+2n) + 1$

$(3n+2)^2 = 9n^2+12n+4 = 3(3n^2+4n + 1) + 1$

From the above, it follows that if $k^2$ is divisible by 3, then $k$ is divisible by 3. **Main question: why does this follow?**

Assume $\sqrt{3}$ is rational. $\sqrt{3} = p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ have no common factor.
$$p^2=3q^2$$
So $p^2$ is divisible by 3, and therefore $p$ is too. $$p=3p'$$ for some natural number $p'$ (**shouldn't it be some integer $p'$?)**

Consequently,

$$(3p')^2=3q^2$$
$$q^2=3p'^2$$

Therefore, $q$ is divisible by 3, a contradiction since this means $p$ and $q$ have a common factor.

Comment: Any integer takes the form $3n$, $3n+1$, or $3n+2$ for some other integer $n$. The calculations show that integers of the latter two types, when squared, are one more than a multiple of three (that's why the extreme right hand sides are written like that), and hence can't square to multiples of three. So if you have a square of an integer that *is* a multiple of three, it must be a square of an integer of the first type, namely, a multiple of three. Depending on your background, there may be nontrivial uses of elementary number theory and formal properties of whole number arithmetic here.

Answer (score 1):

If a number $k$ is *not* a multiple of $3$, then it is of the form $3n+1$ or $3n+2$ for some integer $n$, but then those computations show that $k^2$ is a multiple of $3$ plus $1$; therefore, $k^2$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Concerning your other question, if $\sqrt3$ was rational, it could be written as $\frac pq$, with $p,q\in\Bbb N$. And, if $3\mid p$, then $\frac p3(=p')$ would also be a natural number.

Comment: Considering the solution in Spivak, I think it should be more verbose: any integer k can be written as 3n, 3n+1, or 3n+2 for some integer n; if k is written as 3n+1 or 3n+2, then it is not a multiple of 3, and when we square those expressions, we see that they are also not a multiple of 3. Therefore, if a number k^2 is divisible by 3, it is necessarily the case that k is written as 3n for some integer n, not the other two forms. Hence, if an integer k^2 is divisible by 3, k is also divisible by 3.

Comment: When we assume square root of 3 is rational, why can't p and q possibly both be negative?

Comment: Since $\frac{-p}{-q}=\frac pq$, they can. But why would anyone choose $p$ and $q$ smaller than $0$?

Comment: It is in the realm of possibility, so in the proof p' could be an integer, not just a natural number. Assuming p' is a natural number is an additional assumption, right?

Comment: No, it is not, since every rational number greater than $0$ can be written as the quotient of two natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

1. It follows because we have shown that $(3n+1)^2$ is of the form $3k+1$, meaning that it *cannot* be of the form $3k$ (i.e. it cannot be divisible by $3$). The same reasoning applies for $(3n+2)^2$.
2. Notice that we are assuming that $p,q$ are positive, and since $\frac{p}{3}$ is positive, so is $p'$. It follows because  the natural numbers are the set of positive integers.